# Save Javascript Date.now() millisecond timestamps in TimescaleDB

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, timescaledb

I am trying to store unix timestamps with millisecond precision generated from Javascript's `Date.now()` into a TimescaleDB table `Data` under the column named `timestamp` with type `int8`, or `DataTypes.BIGINT` when using the Javascript library `Sequelize`.

**Question 1:** Is `int8`/`BIGINT` the recommended type to store millisecond unix timestamps in?

**Question 2:** When I try to create the TimescaleDB hypertable using:

```
SELECT create_hypertable('"Data"', 'timestamp', chunk_time_interval => interval '1 day');
```

I get the error message

> ERROR:  invalid interval: must be an integer type for integer dimensions
>   , Time: 0.006000s

Is this because the `interval '1 day'` can not be used with a column of interger type, but only for timestamp and date types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Timescaler here)

1. We recommend using the native timestamptz (timestamp with time zone) or timestamp format whenever possible, rather than integers.  It's microsecond accuracy and is much easier to utilize with time zone conversion, queries using timestamps, now(), etc.  The one time this isn't possible is for nanosecond accuracy (need a bigint), but that doesn't apply here.
2. You are already encountering an issue in using an integer timestamp (rather than timestamp type).  You are setting `chunk_time_interval` to an interval type but your column is an integer.  The problem is that we don't know if your integer represents nanoseconds, seconds, hours, etc., so you can't use something human-readable like '1 day'.  In this case, if your time column is milliseconds, you'd need to specify 86400000.

But in generally, would recommend using timestamptz types if at all possible.